# Postman hangs while making a node.js requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, postman

I'm using postman to make a request to my node.js API, to which I'm using my orders route to send a request following my order controller. Whatever requisition I make using my orders route my requisition hangs and instead of receiving either a 400 or a 500 response, my postman gets stuck on loading screen and it times out after some time. I tried alternatively using the google chrome extension, same results. After the requisition is unsuccessful I receive the following message[image: message]

I was wondering if it has something to do with how I did the routing in my backend, but I am unsure of this. Hence, here's my code:

model.js:

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
    customer: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Customer'
    },
    number: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['created', 'done'],
        default: 'created'
    },
    items: [{
        quantity: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            default: 1
        },
        price: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        product: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Product'
        }
    }],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', schema);
```

post method in my order-controller.js:

```
exports.post = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
        const data = await authService.decodeToken(token);

        await repository.create({
            customer: data.id,
            number: guid.raw().substring(0, 6),
            items: req.body.items
        });
        res.status(201).send({
            message: 'Order registered with success!'
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(500).send({
            message: 'Fail to process your requisition'
        });
    }
};
```

order-repository.js:

```
'use strict';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Order = mongoose.model('Order');

exports.get = async(data) => {
    var res = await Order
        .find({}, 'number status customer items')
        .populate('customer', 'name')
        .populate('items.product', 'title');
    return res;
}

exports.create = async(data) => {
    var order = new Order(data);
    await order.save();
}
```

order-route.js:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const controller = require('../controllers/order-controller');
const authService = require('../services/auth-service');

router.get('/', authService.authorize, controller.get);
router.post('/', authService.authorize, controller.post);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: what does the auth-service look like? Providing this part of the code will allow us to see if the middleware is setup properly

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are debugging your nodejs server and it's caught on a breakpoint. If so, the response will hang. To fix it, just disable that breakpoint, restart your nodejs server, and issue the request again with Postman.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a GET request in the postman instead of POST request.
Make sure that they comply with the type.

Comment: When you use postman to call a backend endpoint that host a GET, but you use POST, one will just get the following from express. This question requires us to know more about the code to figure out why else it could be hanging. 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
 <pre>Cannot POST "your endpoint here"</pre>
</body>

</html>